# How to animate a line increasing its length with time in Python?

Tags: python, animation, plot

I want to show the change of distance between two points a and b with respect to time. That's why I would like to display the segment generated by these two points. Here is a simple example of a horizontal line increasing its length with time. I can't obtain the wished plot! Any help will be more than welcome! Thank you!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

a = [None] * 2
b = [None] * 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=1)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)


def animate(i):
    a[0] = .5 - 0.01*i
    a[1] = .5 + 0.01*i

    b[0] = .5
    b[1] = .5

    line.set_data(a, b)
    return line


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
       frames=45, interval=1, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Thank you so much for your help!